# a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Tags: mysql, oracle

get this error when i am using oracle, but it works fine in mysql

```
left outer join  
 daybreak.contract_details expiring     on
  expiring.acd_id  = 

  (select
 max(lastexpire.acd_id)  

from
 daybreak.contract_details lastexpire  

where lastexpire.acd_aad_id  =acc_aad_id and
  lastexpire.acd_itemization_tcd_code in ('IIN_5') and
  lastexpire.acd_expiry_dt between to_date('2014-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') 
                               and to_date('2014-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and
  lastexpire.acd_term > 0

  )
```

thanks

Comment: what error do you get? Also, is this query complete?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your question?

You cannot specify a subquery in the join condition of an outer join in Oracle.  Doing so will result in an ORA-1799 error.

It's almost always possible to rewrite such a query though. For example, you could:

```
left outer join ( SELECT acd_aad_id, max(acd_id) max_acd_id FROM     daybreak.contract_details lastexpire   WHERE
  lastexpire.acd_itemization_tcd_code in ('IIN_5') and
  lastexpire.acd_expiry_dt between to_date('2014-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') 
                               and to_date('2014-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and
 lastexpire.acd_term > 0 ) max_ids ON max_ids.acd_aad_id = aac_aad_id
left outer join  
daybreak.contract_details expiring     on
 expiring.acd_id  = max_ids.acd_aad_id
```

... the idea being get the value of the subquery for every possible value in an inline view and then outer-join to that.

In Oracle 12c, you could use a `LATERAL` inline view for faster-performing variants of that approach.

An alternate approach would be to just outer join to all the values of `daybreak.contract_details.acd_id`, not just the `max()` value, and then filter out any values that *aren't* the maximum, later on in the query (keeping in mind that some of the values might be null (i.e., if there were no matches in `contract_details` at all).